# ng-click not firing in md-bottom-sheet

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

My apologies in advance for a lengthy post. I wanted to include as much data as possible to see if you could assist me in my problem.

I originally developed the project using Bootstrap as a prototype and proof of concept. Now that I'm planning on going into production, I wanted to use angular-material.

Everything worked perfectly in Bootstrap. However, now that I'm using material design, ng-click is not working now that I'm using md-bottom-sheet. Here is the full code snippets;

### HTML

#### index.html

```
<html ng-app="teamApp">
<head>
    <link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.9.4/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body layout-fill layout-margin layout-padding layout="column" ng-controller="TeamController as teamCtrl">

    <md-toolbar layout="row">
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <md-button class="md-icon-button" hide-gt-sm ng-click="toggleSidenav('left')">
                <md-icon aria-label="Menu" md-svg-icon="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/68133/menu.svg"></md-icon>
            </md-button>
            <h2>Team Builder</h2>
        </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    <div flex layout="row">
        <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" layout="column" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')">
            <md-toolbar layout="row">
                ....
            </md-toolbar>
            <md-list>
                ....
            </md-list>
        </md-sidenav>
    <div flex id="content" layout="column">
        <md-content class="md-padding" flex layout="column">
            <!-- Custom Directive to team-form.html -->
            <team-forms></team-forms>
        </md-content>
    </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.10.1/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/team.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

You will see the team-forms directive. This is a custom directive that pulls in team-form.html. team-form.html has the button that when clicked pops up the md-bottom-sheet.

#### team-form.html

```
<div class="teamForms" layout="column">
    <div id="team-list" class="row" flex>
        <md-list>
            <md-subheader class="md-no-sticky">Teams</md-subheader>
            <md-list-item ng-repeat="team in teams">
                    ........
            </md-list-item>
        </md-list>
    </div>

    <!-- button that when click, makes md-bottom-sheet pop up -->
    <md-button class="md-fab" style="position:absolute; right:0; bottom:0" aria-label="Add Team" ng-click="teamCtrl.showAddTeam($event)">
        <span style="font-size:3em; line-height:1.2em">+</span>
    </md-button>
</div>
```

The HTML template used for the md-bottom-sheet is team-add.html. This is what pops up when the button above is clicked.

#### team-add.html

```
<!-- FORM TO CREATE team -->
<md-bottom-sheet>
{{formData}}
<md-toolbar layout="row">
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
       <h2>Add Team</h2>
    </div>
</md-toolbar>
<form name="add-team">
    <md-content layout-padding layout-sm="column" layout="row">
        <md-input-container>
            <label>Team Name</label>
            <input name="teamName" ng-model="formData.name" required type="text">
        </md-input-container>
     </md-content>
     <div layout="row" ng-show="formData.name.length >= 1">
         <md-input-container>
             <label>Employee Name</label>
             <input class="form-control" name="teamEmployee" ng-model="employee.name" type="text">
         </md-input-container>
         <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="addEmployee(formData)" type="submit">Add</md-button>
      </div>
      <md-content layout="row">
          <md-input-container>
              <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="teamCtrl.createTeam()">Add Team</md-button>
          </md-input-container>
      </md-content>
</form>

</md-bottom-sheet>
```

### JS

#### team.js

```
(function() {
'use strict';

var app = angular.module("teamApp", ["ngMaterial"]);

app.controller("TeamController", ["$scope", "$http", "$mdSidenav", "$mdBottomSheet", function($scope, $http, $mdSidenav, $mdBottomSheet) {
    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.formData.employees = [];

    // when landing on the page, get all teams and show them
    $http.get("/api/teams")
        .success(function(data) {
        $scope.teams = data;
    })
        .error(function(data) {
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });

    $scope.toggleSidenav = function(menuId) {
        $mdSidenav(menuId).toggle();
    };

    this.showAddTeam = function($event) {
        $mdBottomSheet.show({
            templateUrl: 'directives/team/team-add.html',
            targetEvent: $event
        })
    };

    this.resetForms = function() {
        $scope.teamForm = false;
        $scope.employeeForm = false;
    };

    this.getTeam = function(id) {
        $http.get("/api/teams/" + id)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.singleTeam = data;
                console.log('Success: ' + data);
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
        };

    // when submitting the add form, send the text to the node API
    this.createTeam = function() {
        $http.post("/api/teams", $scope.formData)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.formData = {}; // clear the form so our user is ready to enter another
                $scope.formData.employees = [];
                $scope.teams = data;
                console.log(data);
            })
           .error(function(data) {
               console.log('Error: ' + data);
           });
        };

    this.updateTeam = function(id) {
        $http.put("/api/teams/" + id, $scope.singleTeam[0])
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.singleTeam = {};
                $scope.teams = data;
                console.log('Success: ' + data);
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
        };

  // delete a todo after checking it
  this.deleteTeam = function(id) {
    $http.delete("/api/teams/" + id)
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.teams = data;
        console.log(data);
      })
      .error(function(data) {
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
      });
  };


  this.getRotation = function() {
    $http.post("/api/rotations")
      .success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .error(function(data) {
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
      });
  };

}]);

app.directive("teamForms", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: "directives/team/team-forms.html",
    controller: ["$scope", function($scope) {
      $scope.employee = {};
      $scope.teamForm = false;
      $scope.employeeForm = false;

      this.showTeamForm = function(value) {
        return $scope.teamForm == value;
      };

      this.setTeamForm = function(value) {
        $scope.teamForm = value;
      };

      this.showEmployeeForm = function(value) {
        return $scope.employeeForm == value;
      };

      this.setEmployeeForm = function(value) {
        $scope.employeeForm = value;
      };

      $scope.addEmployee = function(dataSet) {
        dataSet.employees.push($scope.employee);
        $scope.employee = {};
      };

      $scope.removeEmployee = function(dataSet, index) {
        dataSet.employees.splice(index, 1);
      };
    }],
    controllerAs: "teamFormCtrl"
  };
});

app.directive("teamEditForm", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: "directives/team/team-edit.html"
  };
});
}());
```

The issue is in the team-add.html. It's the md-button that is trying to call createTeam().

The expected result is that it would post the name of the team to my API endpoint and into my mongoDB setup. This was working perfectly before in bootstrap but I feel that now I'm deeper in the UI with how md-bottom-sheet needs to be setup, that I have some scoping or controller issue in place.

I have even tried adding a fake, non-existent function to ng-click to see if some error was thrown when clicked but no error showed up. Node is not even reporting a post command being sent. It just seems that the button is doing absolutely nothing

Any help would be greatly appreciated and if more code is needed, please let me know and I'll post it up!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your `md-button` your `ng-click` is something like this

```
<md-button class="md-fab"
    ng-click="teamCtrl.showAddTeam($event)">
```

Your question reads "ng-click not firing", to make ng-click work give this a try

```
ng-click="showAddTeam($event)">
```

This will work since you are trying to call a function which is in some controller and your directive's html is within at controller's scope only.

Comment: Hey Yasser, thanks for the quick reply. That portion of the code is working fine. The issue is in team-add.html, the ng-click that is calling createTeam(). I have revised my question to make this more clear. :-)